# How to collapse/merge two different graphs having same node and combining the properties in neo4j graph database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I have two graphs with node name as "URL" and Property as TC_1(for graph1), TC_2 (for graph2). Now I want to merge/collapse those two graphs to attain a network where merging will be done on the basis of equal node name and properties(TC_X) should be combined using apoc. 
 `sc:API {URL: url , TC : "TC_002"})`
Here URL is node of type API and TC is property.

```
MATCH (x:API)-[:NEXT]->(x:API)
WITH x, collect(x) as subgraph
CALL apoc.nodes.collapse(subgraph,{properties:'combine'}) yield from, rel, to
return from, rel, to
```

Code shows success but I do not get any output.

Comment: why both variable name is x?
`MATCH (x:API)-[:NEXT]->(x:API)`

Answer (score 0):

**`apoc.nodes.collapse`** create a single virtual node for the list of nodes passed and return it.

**Virtual node** means its created and returned to UI, but are not stored in the database.
So here code will show success but it will not change the database.

To make changes in the database you need to use [**`apoc.refactor.mergeNodes`**](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#merge-nodes) instead of **`apoc.nodes.collapse`**.